# Getting SUM for hh:mm:ss in EXCEL

Tags: excel, time, sum, ms-office, formula

I'm working with a document where I need to get the SUM of various values for time spent on calls and assign/display that value in a totals cell. I've attached an image of the data I'm working with. The entries are in hh:mm:ss format, and the cell receiving them is in [hh]:mm:ss format. The formula is =SUM(C2:C11). I am still getting a 00:00:00 value in the totals cell despite adding the brackets to the format. Can anyone help with this? Much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Most likely your "times" in C2:C11 are stored as text.

Comment: Try: `=SUMPRODUCT(--C2:C11)` instead of your sum.

Answer (score 2):

To put my comments in an answer.

Most likely the times are stored as text.

`SUM` will ignore text and is why it will return `0`.

One option is to convert the text into a true time, but since the time is in a format that Excel can recognize as a time we can do it in the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--C2:C11)
```

The `--` will force the text into a number and the SUMPRODUCT will iterate the array and sum the results.

With Office 365 we can use `SUM`

```
=SUM(--C2:C11)
```

Older versions will need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter if `SUM` is used instead of `SUMPRODUCT` which will not require it in any version.